# Is an inputless program redundant?

Tags: programming-practices

Are there useful programs that don't take inputs such as:
A user's keyboard input;
an interrupt from a clock;
data from another server etc.

A program that computed/printed out predefined data could be turned into a file, right?

Comment: How about a program that computes the digits of pi? How about a program intended to compute the answer for some mathematical problems, where the "input" is hard-coded into the program itself (during programming or compilation phase)?

Comment: The answer is `yes(1)`    :-)

Comment: So, is the only example mathematical approximation?

Comment: A dead man's switch that doesn't require configuration.  Well, I guess that would take a timer as input, though you could approximate a timer by sitting in a loop.  Really, any program where you hard-wire the input data.

Comment: When you say "redundant", do you really mean "useless" ?

Comment: The use of the word "useful" in question details denotes so.

Comment: By "input", does the data from server serves as input too? Because I'm thinking of a pure information app that doesn't need user interaction, but the data is served from server to make it more manageable.

Comment: "*...inputs from a user, environment etc. such as key input, or the current time* [or a server]"

Comment: This question was unrightfully placed on hold.

Comment: In it's simplest form, a dice roller.  They usually have user inputs that determine what to roll but you certainly could have one that doesn't, or you could have one where the input is on the command line and you could call it with a batch file that provided predefined input--the batch file would thus become a program with zero input.

Comment: Inputless programs can have useful side-effects. An inputless _pure_ program could probably be converted to a flat file.

Answer (score 9):

One example where such a program can be useful is when the program is much shorter than its output. That means that the program is basically a compressed version of its output.

Some practical use cases:

- **Self-extracting zip files**
- Programs whose output is actually **infinite**, such as  `yes(1)` which repeatedly outputs "y". (Thanks to blrfl for mentioning this in a comment.)

The theoretical term for this concept (when the output is finite) is **Kolmogorov complexity**. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Kolmogorov_complexity&oldid=758376748#Definition):

> Consider the following two strings of 32 lowercase letters and digits:
>
> ```
> abababababababababababababababab
>
> 4c1j5b2p0cv4w1x8rx2y39umgw5q85s7
> ```
>
> The first string has a short English-language description, namely "ab
>   16 times", which consists of 11 characters. The second one has no
>   obvious simple description (using the same character set) other than
>   writing down the string itself, which has 32 characters.
>
> More formally, the complexity of a string is the length of the
>   shortest possible description of the string in some fixed universal
>   description language [...].

(Note: This fixed universal description language is usually some Turing-complete programming language.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, unit tests (at least decently written ones).

#### Edit

*To be less glib*: There are a lot of different unit test setups but they effectively boil down to the following, the code base under test is treated as a library and your unit tests are essentially one big program that when run prints out something like

```
Test foo passed
Test bar passed
Test baz failed
     ...Details...
Test quux passed
```

If your unit tests are deterministic (which they generally should be as debugging nondeterministic tests is the worst), this will just be a constant string.

Now once you get into the real world the border's really fuzzy here, but I think the general point that an inputless program is a good way of learning about some other set of source code.

Comment: I thought unit tests take code as an input, to test?

Comment: @Tobi, hopefully the edit brings the point out.

Comment: I'm confused; will a unit test not test code you've written, making it an input?

Comment: @Tobi well, *no* ... Unit tests don't read the implementation like an input or environmental resource, they *include* the implementation *during compilation.* In order to generate pretty, interactive results, a the test suite usually interacts with the environment (like an IDE or test runner). But, that's optional, really. It could just as easily be a binary that executes on its own and dumps the results to standard out. And in fact, I've cowboyed some test runners of that nature myself...

Answer (score 4):

Lots of system utilities. The shutdown, reboot, poweroff commands.

There are others I can't think of right now, I'm sure.

Answer (score 2):

Programs like this occasionally arise and are useful such as to answer a specific question by performing some calculations. But once the program works correctly and produces the result, there is no need to run it anymore.

As an example, I once wrote such a program to produce a set of matrices that convert Euler angles to an orthogonal matrix for all the possible Euler angle systems.  The input was essentially generated within the program (a set of permutations).  The program symbolically multiplied 3 or 2 matrices together for each possible Euler angle system and produced a TeX file with the resulting matrices.  It was less work and less error-prone to write the program than to do the math by hand.  There was no input from the environment, though.  You just ran the command and it wrote out the file.  And once I was satisfied that it was working correctly, I haven't run it again since.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by redundant.  Here are a few I could think of in a couple minutes:

- A program that creates music or art
- A program that dances, or sends instructions to a robot that dances
- A program that models a virtual society and outputs its likely lifespan under varying conditions
- A radio beacon

Are any of those things redundant?

Comment: All of those things will have input, even if it's coming from a random seed.

Comment: #1: What do mean "creates music or art"? Randomly = Seeded by an input #2: That would be an input into an interpreter that controls the robotic movement. #3: An inputted society or a randomly generated one? The latter would be seeded #4: What do you mean by "radio beacon"?..

Comment: Incorrect; none of the items I listed require *in*put, as in, something traversing from outside the system to inside the system.  And I don't know where you got the idea that randomness is a requirement for any of it.

Comment: #1 I mean literally composes a piece of music or draws a picture. It doesn't have to be very good music or a very interesting picture. Neither randomness nor originality is a requirement. #2. No, it would be an *out*put to an interpreter that controls the robotic movement. #3. Neither; a society that determines itself, starting with a basic initial condition, then evolving.  #4. A continual transmission in the electromagnetic spectrum, modulated by the output of our program, potentially in accordance with a predetermined pattern.

Comment: Many novelties and children's toys have no input; when powered, they carry out (often repeat) a pre-determined sequence until the power is disconnected or runs down. A music box probably wouldn't count as a "program" for this question, but a toy dog or robot could easily have a microprocessor simply because it's easier than the discrete components

Answer (score 1):

A program which computes the sequence of prime numbers.

Comment: A program that calculates the number of primes less than 10^k for 1 <= k <= 30. There’s no chance to get the numbers without running a rather clever program for a substantial time on a large number of computers.